# Centering to use a sparse covariate?

Tags: regression, logistic, missing-data, centering

In my dataset, there's a binary response, some factors, and some covariates. In particular, there are some covariates that are always present when `factor1=="A"` and these covariates are always missing (`NA`) when `factor1=="B"`. This missingness is structural, not random; it doesn't make sense for the covariate to have a value when `factor1=="B"`.

To fit this as a logistic regression, I centered the covariates about the mean, and then set the covariate to 0 wherever it had been `NA`. I reason that in this way, the effect of the covariate on the response will be nullified whenever `factor1=="B"`, which is appropriate.

Is this a reasonable approach to fitting these data?

What is the name for this approach, and where (web, textbook) is there a good discussion?

Comment: Note, that after removing the mean from your regressor you will not fit it anymore. So you have to potentially include an additional regressor to distinguish NA and non-NA cases.

Comment: I know I can [add an indicator regressor](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6563/8207), but why is re-centering not sufficient? What do you mean by "you will not fit it anymore"?

Comment: Effectively you are only fitting the slope with your new regressor, and no intercept. This might or might not be correct in your case. If you are unsure, I'd fit the model with and without indicator regressor and try to understand the output.