# how to deal with independent variable of value 0 when applying log-log model?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, data-transformation

I am trying to apply log-log in a marketing mix model. The dependent variable is sales, among the independent variables, one is holiday, it is dummy variable, the value is either 1(yes), or 0 (no). Another variable is competitor spend, sometimes, the value is 0.

I want to use a log-log model in R. But how can deal with variables like holiday and competitor's spend which have value of 0? I cannot remove these two variables from the model.

I already did a linear regression model in R, can anyone help me with the log-log model? (As suggested by a comment in below, I used log(x+1) in the log-log model, is it correct?)

```
model <- lm(SALES ~ HOLIDAY + AVERAGE_PRICE + COMPETITOR_MEDIA_SPEND
        + IMP_TV + IMP_EMAIL + IMP_PAID_SEARCH + IMP_ONLINE_DISPLAY
        + IMP_PRODUCT_SEARCH, data = mmm)


model2 <- lm(log(SALES) ~ log(HOLIDAY+1) + log(AVERAGE_PRICE) 
         + log(COMPETITOR_MEDIA_SPEND+1)+ log(IMP_TV) + log(IMP_EMAIL) 
         + log(IMP_PAID_SEARCH) + log(IMP_ONLINE_DISPLAY)
         + log(IMP_PRODUCT_SEARCH), data = mmm)
```

Comment: Some people use log(x+1) in situations like this.

Comment: Another possible road to go down is a [zero inflated model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model).

Comment: See [80% of missing data in a single variable](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6563/17230) & [How small a quantity should be added to x to avoid taking the log of zero?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30728/17230). And, as @Carl explains, transforming indicator variables really makes no difference - you could just as well set HOLIDAY to $\pi$ for 'yes' & $7$ for 'no'.

Comment: @Scortchi Correct. The only advantage of using $x=\{1(no), 2(yes)\}$ is that $c_x\ln x\rightarrow x^{c_x}\rightarrow\{1^{c_x}=1,2^{c_x}\}$. That is, that $2^{c_x}$ is simply the adjustment factor for a yes answer. In other words, if we have one answer as the multiplicative identity ($=1$), the scaling is easier to understand.

Comment: @MatthewGunn How using a [Poisson model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model) would you adjust for the disagreement between the square root makes normal residuals of a Poisson model and the logarithm makes normal residuals for a proportional error (log) model? Or, perhaps that is besides the point and you were just giving a general indication of the direction in which another solution may lie without specifying explicitly how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathit{HOLIDAY}_t$ is a binary, [indicator variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)), then there's absolutely no reason to compute $X_t = \log(1 + \mathit{HOLIDAY}_t)$. Just stick the indicator $\mathit{HOLIDAY}_t$ on the right hand side of the regression.

#### Table of values:

$$\begin{array}{ccc} \text{Is day $t$ a holiday?} & \mathit{HOLIDAY}_t & \log(1 + \mathit{HOLIDAY}_t) \\
\text{no} & 0 & 0  \\ \text{yes} & 1 & \log(2) \end{array}$$

You're basically creating an indicator variable where it takes the value $\log(2)$ (which is $\approx .6931$) if the condition is true. IMHO, this is bizarre.

#### Two equivalent regressions:

A regression of:
$$y_t = a + b_1 \mathit{HOLIDAY}_t + \epsilon_t$$

is equivalent to a regression of:
$$y_t = a + b_2 \log(1+\mathit{HOLIDAY}_t) + \epsilon_t$$

in the sense that your estimate $\hat{b}_2 = \frac{\hat{b}_1}{\log(2)}$ since $\log(1 + \mathit{HOLIDAY}_t) = \log(2)\mathit{HOLIDAY}_t$.

#### Conclusion (weirdo transforms hurt interpretability)

If you ran the regression $\log(Sales_t) = a + b \, \mathit{HOLIDAY}_t + \epsilon_t$ and got an estimate for $b$ of .02, you would basically conclude that sales are 2 percent higher on holidays.

If you ran the regression $\log(Sales_t) = a + b \log(1 + HOLIDAY_t) + \epsilon_t$, you would then get an estimate of $.02 / \log(2)$ = .0289, which has absolutely no meaningful interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that is much simpler than one might fear. There are many solutions, and here is the one I use. I set 1(no) and 2(yes). Now what that does is create Log(no)=0 and Log(yes)=Log(2). Now, one could set $e$(yes) so that Log(yes)=1, but that actually makes no difference to the regression significance.

Here is a link to a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6707938_An_improved_method_for_determining_renal_sufficiency_using_volume_of_distribution_and_weight_from_bolus_Tc-99m-DTPA_two_blood_sample_paediatric_data) using 1=male, and 2=female, for ordinary least squares log-log (i.e., power function) modelling.

The other question is for the value 0 occurring in a real variable. One can, for example do as @DavidLane suggests and use Log(1+x). However, that can alter the regression. Another possibility is to use 1(no spending) and x(spending) to yield Log(no spending)=0 and Log(spending)=Log(x). There are many other solutions and approaches. For example, if zero is within the range of a continuous variable, it may be that $\sqrt x$ is a better transform than $\ln x$. What is best depends on what the best transformation is for that portion of the data, and, it is possible, and sometimes necessary to transform different variables differently. See [power transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform). This link includes (thank-you @horaceT) the Box-Cox transform, which is a log transform that you might like to use.

Comment: So log(x+1) can be used for the dummy variables but not for continuous variables, right?@Carl

Comment: What you asked was about binary variables, for which I answered 1, 2. If the data is truly proportional type, for a continuous variable Log(1+x) would not be exactly proportional modelling. Which is why I suggested to using Log(x) for all spending except no spending, which would then be Log(1)=0. What that does after detransforming the additive term in the logarithm $+k\ln x$ is make a multiplicative term $x^k$, where $x$ is spending, and $k$ is determined by regression.

Comment: @Carl Can you cite a reference for the log(no spending) method?

Comment: @horaceT No, nor am I suggesting it as other than a possibility. It is a counter argument to using $\ln (x+1)$ rather than a recommendation. I am using it to demonstrate what $\ln (x+1)$ is not. I can try to think of another work around, but in practice if I have zeros, my reflex reaction would be to test if a power function or other transform is not preferable to a logarithm, and typically I find one, so I have not had the problem occur in practice.

Comment: @Carl The two-parameter Box-Cox transform could handle x=zero, that may be one solution. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform)