# How do we obtain the combined level's HR or OR in a regression model?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, inference, survival

I would like to perform a cox PH model. I have identified 4 covariates to investigate the association with survival time.  2 of the covariates are `trauma` and `workplace_injury` each taking either `Y` or `N`. `workplace_injury` is not available for all observations, but only for `trauma == "Y"`. Hence, those with `trauma == "N"` will have missing values for `workplace_injury`, and as a result, these observations will be removed from the model. Let's name the remaining 2 covariates as `A` and `B` to simplify.

[image]

So, I have decided to combine the 2 covariates into 1 covariate, as seen in the last column, i.e. `trauma_wi`.
[image]

Using `"NonTrauma"` as the reference on the model (`A+B+trauma_wi`), the result is as follows (I cropped out the results for `A` and `B`):
[image]

**My first question:**
How do I combine the results (i.e. combine the estimates), such that I can make a comparison between Trauma (`Trauma_Y` and `Trauma_N`) and NonTrauma?

**My second question:**
Would the results be the same if I were to run the model (`A+B+trauma`), i.e. ignoring the `workplace_injury`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The potential problem with what you seek to do is that, if there is a difference between `workplace_injury=="Y"` and `workplace_injury=="N"`, as there seems to be, then the value of a regression coefficient that only evaluates `trauma` as in your second question will depend on the relative prevalence of `workplace_injury` in your data sample. If outcomes are worse with `workplace_injury=="Y"` then the overall apparent association with `trauma` will be progressively worse for data samples weighted toward greater prevalence of `workplace_injury=="Y"`.

There's nothing wrong with that in principle. If your data are representative of an underlying population and your interest is in a population-average estimate for the effect of `trauma`, that might be what you want. But you have to understand that and make that clear to your audience.

You might consider having separate predictors for `trauma` and `workplace_injury` in your model. Logically, if `trauma=="N"` then also `workplace_Injury=="N"` so you could code all your `trauma=="N"` cases that way. That's an accepted way to deal with situations in regression like this, when one predictor only takes non-zero values if another predictor has a non-zero value, as explained in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6565/28500). Then you could use ANOVA to compare the nested models

```
model1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status)~A+B+trauma+workplace_injury

model2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status)~A+B+trauma
```

to evaluate the statistical significance and practical importance of `workplace_injury`, and proceed accordingly. The coefficients that you get from my `model1` should correspond to what you have in your 3-level categorical model, with the `trauma` coefficient in my `model1` the same as your regression coefficient for `trauma_wiTrauma_N` and your regression coefficient for `trauma_wiTrauma_Y` being the sum of the `trauma` and `workplace_injury` coefficients in my `model1`.* You should be able to get the same results either way, but I at least find it easier to think about the `trauma` and `workplace_injury` terms separately, particularly for evaluating the significance and importance of the different `workplace_injury` values.

---

*I find it best to do these types of intermediate analyses with the original (additive) `coef` values, rather than working with their exponentiations into multiplicative hazard ratios. You can then express the final results in terms of hazard ratios once you've added the individual coefficients appropriately.