# Interaction terms for an incomplete design R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interaction

I'm trying to fit a GLM on some data and I feel like there should be an interaction term between two of the explanatory variables (one categorical and one discrete) but all the non-zero instances of the discrete variable occur on the "1" state of the categorical variable (partly why I feel like there should be an interaction). When I put the interaction in the glm (var1*var2), it just shows N/A for the interaction term (var1:var2) in the summary ANOVA.

I have Included a mock example below

```
a <- data.frame("y" <- c(0,1,2,3),
                "var1" <- c(0,1,1,1),
                "var2" <- c(0,0,1,2))
a.glm <- glm(y ~ var1*var2, family=poisson, data = a)
summary(a.glm)
```

and then this shows up in the console:

```
Call:
glm(formula = y ~ var1 * var2, family = poisson, data = a)

Deviance Residuals: 
       1         2         3         4  
-0.00002  -0.08284   0.12401  -0.04870  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -22.303  42247.166    0.00     1.00
var1           22.384  42247.166    0.00     1.00
var2            0.522      0.534    0.98     0.33
var1:var2          NA         NA      NA       NA

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 4.498681  on 3  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.024614  on 1  degrees of freedom
AIC: 13.63

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 20
```

This is the table giving the mean of y for each combination in my actual data.
|    |   0   |   1   |   2   |   3   |

| 0  | 1.592 |  N/A  |  N/A  |  N/A  |

| 1  | 1.859 | 1.759 | 1.543 | 0.813 |

|mean| 1.721 | 1.759 | 1.543 | 0.813 |

I'd rather not make var2 categorical as there clearly seems to be a negative correlation between var2 and y which is being overshadowed by the var1 = 0 values. (there are relatively few observations of var2 = 2 and 3 which does not help overcome this effect)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You say "all the non-zero instances of the discrete variable occur on the "1" state of the categorical variable" but either this is not reflected in your mock example OR *some* zero-cases of the discrete variable *also* show up in the "1" state of your categorical. Which is it?

Comment: All the non-zero cases and some zero cases are in the "1" state and only zero cases are in the "0" state. I'm pretty sure the "all the non-zero instances of the discrete variable occur on the "1" state of the categorical variable" and "some zero-cases of the discrete variable also show up in the "1" state of the categorical" are not contradictory. In either case, that's beside the point. My data is similar to the example.

Comment: In your example, the product of `var1` and `var2` is perfectly collinear with `var2`.  That seems to be the problem.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Do you have any idea on how I could model the interaction then?

Comment: @Kon-kon in your toy example, `y` is generated according to a very specific process. I think you'll find if you generate more samples, and perhaps some randomness to the response, you will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to set up a new categorical predictor based on the *combinations* of predictor values for which you have data. A full interaction term between a binary predictor and a 3-level categorical predictor would require fitting 5 coefficients. You only have 4 combinations with values. So you could define a new 4-level categorical predictor $x_{ij}$ with $i$ being the level of `var1` and $j$ being the corresponding level of `var2`. You would define $x_{00}$, $x_{10}$, $x_{11}$ and $x_{12}$ in your example. Then use $x_{ij}$ as the predictor in your model instead of `var1` and `var2`.

That allows you to evaluate the overall association of the predictors with outcome and differences among particular combinations of `var1` and `var2`. That's not the same as a standard interaction term, but it's something you can do with the data you have.

If you want to treat `var2` as a linear predictor (with only a few levels), and if the nature of the subject matter is such that you can have non-zero values for `var2` *only* when `var1=1` (with `var2=0` still possible when `var1=1`), then you can use the approach on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6563/28500). Write your model without the interaction term:

```
glm(formula = y ~ var1 + var2, family = poisson, data = a)
```

The Intercept of the model is the estimated outcome (in the log-link scale) for `var1=0` (for all of which `var2=0` also). The coefficient for `var1` is the estimated outcome at `var2=0` when `var1=1`. The coefficient for `var2` then evaluates your hypothesis that there is a linear relationship between `var2` and outcome.

If there could theoretically be non-zero values of `var2` when `var1=0` you can still model `var2` continuously as above, but then you have to be very careful when interpreting your data. You only have information about the association of `var2` with outcome when `var1=1`, you can't say anything about the association of `var2` with outcome when `var1=1`, and you thus have no information about a possible interaction between `var1` and `var2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that if there is no better way. I'm pretty sure there is a relation between y and var2 though which gets ignored when the 0 values for var 2 are pooled together, so I'd rather not make var2 categorical.

Comment: @Kon-kon I've added a suggestion for how to treat `var2` as a linear predictor. You don't get a formal "interaction" evaluation, but you can evaluate its association with outcome for the `var1=1` situation, as well as the association of `var1=1` with outcome in the `var2=0` situation.

Comment: Thank you! My data is about pandas and var1 is if they are "paired" and var2 is how many offspring they have, so none of the unpaired pandas have offspring but the issue is that some of the paired ones do, so sadly I don't think your answer works. It was quite insightful though.

Comment: @Kon-kon the situation you describe is what my later suggestion covers. If I understand correctly, unpaired pandas (`var1=0`) _by necessity_ have 0 offspring. Paired pandas might have 0, 1, 2 or more. Your `var1` is like the "loan indicator" on the [page I linked](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6563/28500), and `var2` is like the "loan amount." It's not a problem that some paired pandas also have 0 offspring; the coefficient for `var1` is the difference between paired and unpaired at 0 offspring. The coefficient for `var2` is the change in outcome beyond that for each additional offspring.

Comment: Thank you I'll give it another read. I thought you mentioned that it var1=1 needed to have *only* non-zero offspring.

Comment: @Kon-kon I see where the confusion might have arisen. I'll reword.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142222/discussion-between-kon-kon-and-edm).