# Whether to transform non-normal independent variables in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, normal-distribution, data-transformation

I recently received the following email, which I paraphrase below:

> I want to do binomial logistic
>   regression with the data and I have non-normally distributed IVs.  I tried doing square root transformation on
>   the non-normal IVs.  This was
>   successful in normalising the distribution; however, when I did the
>   logistic regression on the data I got ridiculous results i.e. OR: 14,
>   CI 6 - 180.  So I transformed the variables back by squaring them, and
>   then ran the analysis again.

#### Questions

- Why do the odds ratios look ridiculous after applying square root transformation?
- Should one apply the square root transformation to non-normal predictors when doing logistic regression?

Answer (score 11):

#### Why odds ratios look strange on transformed variables

Transformations change the metric of the variable. Odds ratios are the predicted difference in odds for a **one unit** increase on the IV holding all other IVs constant. The meaning of **one unit** will be very different after a square root transformation.

For example, if you had a 1 to 100 raw scale, then after transformation, the difference between 16 and 25 on the raw scale would be the same as the difference between 4 and 5 on the square root transformed scale. Thus, it's not surprising that your odds ratios became a lot larger after square root transformation.

If you want to examine the effect of the transformation in a scaling-neutral way, you could standardise your IVs (i.e., make them z-scores). Thus, you could compare the odds ratio of a z-score of the raw variable to a z-score of the transformed variable. This will allow you to isolate the effect of changing the relative distance between categories.

#### Whether to transform non-normal predictors in logistic regression

Normality of predictors is not an assumption of logistic regression, or linear regression for that matter. See [@whuber's answer here for more details](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4833/183).

That said, you may find one scaling of your IVs more predictive or interpretable. I'd use criteria like that to decide whether you want to transform a predictor variable.

Comment: Observations with outliers in an IV tend to highly influence the parameter estimates of the model. In such a case, transformations might be an option.