# R/Python: continuous & binary interaction term still drops observations

Tags: r, regression, python, interaction

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```r
> df <- data.frame(y = c(1, 0, 0, 1), x1 = c(3.5, NA, NA, 4.5), 
                   x2 = c(0, 1, 1, 0))
> df
  y  x1 x2
1 1 3.5  0
2 0  NA  1
3 0  NA  1
4 1 4.5  0
```

`y` is my dependent variable, `x1` is some continuous predictor, and `x2` is a binary indicator with values of 1 when `x1` is null else 0. I've read that, in lieu of imputing something like the median for a continuous feature, it would be better to use an indicator variable to say that feature is null for a particular case.

However, I'm struggling with the implementation in code of this model. R's default behavior (as is the same for Python's `statsmodels.formula.api`) is to drop records where any predictor is null. See below. This effectively defeats the purpose of having the indicator variable `x2`, since the records for which the indicator would appear are dropped:

```r
> summary(lm(y ~ ., data=df))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = df)

Residuals:
ALL 2 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 1.00e+00         NA      NA       NA
x1          3.14e-16         NA      NA       NA
x2                NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:    NaN, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 1 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA

> summary(lm(y ~ x1 * x2, data=df))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 * x2, data = df)

Residuals:
ALL 2 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 1.00e+00         NA      NA       NA
x1          3.14e-16         NA      NA       NA
x2                NA         NA      NA       NA
x1:x2             NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:    NaN, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 1 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

Is there some syntactic sugar I'm missing here? How can I best encode my model?

Comment: Set the NAs to zero.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4833/919 for an explanation.

Comment: Setting to zero after standardizing the predictors.