# Log Transformation Before Modeling

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation

I have the following distribution:

[image]

I have numerous zero values which I change to 1 so I don't have zero or negative numbers before I log transform.  Of course, log(1) = 0. So I get the following results:

[image]

Of course, the log transform has given me more of a normal distribution except for the lower end of the data.  Does the spike mean that performing the transformation is meaningless?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This is input data.  Many models work best when the input is normally distributed.  When faced with an exponential distribution I apply a log transformation. But the lower end value give me the spike in the otherwise more normally distributed data.  Therefore, does it make sense to NOT transform this data?

Comment: What model are you using that requires normally-distributed inputs?

Comment: Most parametric models do better when inputs are gaussian.  Linear regression, naive bayes

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica should clarify if "scaling" means dividing by SD so that variance=1, linear regression is *not* invariant to power transforms (of which log is a special case). Also a few network based analyses like SEM require normal inputs because prespecified network structures place constraints on the working covariance structure d/t independence assumptions.

Comment: @AdamO My interest in this line of questioning is identifying whether OP's question is essentially an XY problem. Right now, I think it might be. I agree that a power transformation is a different OLS model than a model of non-transformed data, but it's not obvious that is the problem that OP wishes to solve. If OP's motivation is "OLS only works for normally-distributed inputs," that seems worth addressing.

Comment: Input data is not "required" to be transformed.  However, many models perform better when input data is gaussian.  It is common practice to transform non-gaussian input data.  Sometimes it improves things - sometimes not.

Comment: We find many people asking questions predicated on this "common practice"--but it's usually based on the wrong considerations.  "Parametric" is not the same as "Gaussian;" response variables usually *ought* to have complex distributions that reflect their explanatory variables; most parametric assumptions pertain to *error* terms, not to the variables themselves; whether and how to transform a variable depends on how it will be used in an analysis; and much more. Thus, you might or might not have a problem here and your approach might make the situation better, worse, or not matter.

Comment: Some relevant threads include https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30728 (on taking logs of data with zero values), https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35711 (on transforming a response variable), and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4831 (on transforming regression variables).

Comment: I didn't say that "parametric" is the same as "Gaussian".  I said that sometimes parametric models perform better with gaussian distributed inputs - hence the reason for the transform.  Applying transformations where applicable is a fundamental approach to data preparation prior to model evaluation and selection.

Comment: @whuber your suggestion https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4831/regression-transforming-variables is very helpful

Answer (score 2):

If the response is count valued, you should consider using an appropriate modeling strategy that implicitly log-transforms the intensity rather than the count values themselves. Consider that a Poisson process with low intensity is likely to have right skewed results and many 0s, but log-transforms of the data would lead to highly biased estimates of the mean and of the SD, regardless of how the 0 values are handled. Fitting negative binomial or quasipoisson GLM as probabilistic models via MLE is a simple, straightforward, and efficient way to summarize count data where applicable.

A log-transform alternative that has been explored for variables with 0 values is logp1, where 1 is added *to every value* before applying log transform, and not just to the 0 value. This will decrease the intensity of the truncation, but not satisfactorily. In other words, your approach is not justified regardless of the distribution's appearance *post hoc*. The resulting scatterplot is evidence of this.

If the response is continuously valued, the distribution has mixture properties and mixture modeling is one approach to estimating a density with better precision that the proposed approach.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to separate your data into 2 variables. One with an indicator of the value is zero or non zero. And the other being value of the variable given a non zero variable. And then apply the transformation.
On a separate note you can try using power transform/box Cox transform.

Comment: Boxcox with unspecified Lambda on this series gave a value of 0.04 - which is virtually the log transformation.

Comment: True. But it should be remembered that Box Cox transformations have a limitation that data should be positive which is applicable for log transformation as well. So better approach is to remove non positive data points and keep them in a separate variable which should make your data probably an exponential.