# How do I choose which variable transformation (logY~logX/logY~X/etc)?

Tags: r, regression, log-linear

I'm doing a linear regression assignment using a variable transformation using R.
and I have several questions.

1. What is the criteria of choosing which type of variable transformation?
   We've learnt "Y~X", "logY~X", "logY~logX". Out of three, how can I choose the model?

1-1. Should I look at the plot line? It is as below (Company 1 and 2). I drew the line using loess. If so, I think Company 1 should have Y~X (without transformation) because plot itself looks quite linear; Company 2 should have logY~BlogX with negative coefficient B.

Company 1
[image][image]

Company 2
[image][image]

1-2. Can highest adjusted R squared be a criteria? Someone says the dependent variable should be same, which means it cannot be used as a criteria because Y and logY are not same.

2. When I use logY~logX model, should I log the intercept? For example, the model would be like logY = (intercept) + BlogX + e. If so, should I log the intercept when I write the final model equation? Or is it already logged?
3. When I transform the model with a dummy variable and variable including 0, what can I do? For example, my model should be
   logY = Intercept + BlogX1 + X2 (dummy) + X3 (including zeros).
   Can I just leave X2 and X3 as it is, without logging?

3-1. Then the same question with 2. Should I log the result coefficients of X2 and X3?

I'm so lost.....
Thank you so so much!!!! Have wonderful days! XD

Comment: Answers to your first question are at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4831.  Study those and move on from there.